# this.$refs, this.$router, this.$route access with Vue 2 Composition API

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router, vue-composition-api

Can you please tell me how to access `this.$refs`, `this.$router`, `this.$route` in Vue 2 Composition API setup function? There are solutions mentioned with `context.$root` but `$root` is not available with `context` anymore. Please help.

I am using Vue 2 with Composition API plugin. It seems `useRoute` or `useRouters` doesn't support Vue 2 router version. `useRoute` and `useRouters` are available with Vue-router v4.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could import the router from its module and access both `router` and `route` from it.

Refs can be used the same way as in Vue 3:

```js
import { ref, onMounted } from "@vue/composition-api";   // import ref, onMounted
import router from "@/router";                           // import router

export default {
  setup() {
    console.log(router);                                 // this.$router
    console.log(router.app.$route);                      // this.$route

    const myref = ref(null);                             // create ref
    onMounted(() => {
      console.log(myref);                                // this.$refs.myref
    });

    return { myref };                                    // return for template ref
  },
};
```